# Open url in existing browser not in default browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-webbrowser

I used below code to open new url

```
webbrowser.open(url)
```

This opened the url in the default browser, but I need to open it in a browser session that is already open.

Also, is there a way to open a URL in a specific tab of a browser?

Comment: Still doesn't have anything to do with Django.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `webbroser.get([name])`:  Return a controller object for the browser type name. If name is empty, return a controller for a default browser appropriate to the caller’s environment.

**Demo:**

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://www.google.com'
browser = webbrowser.get('firefox') # or lynx, opera
browser.open(url)
```

Comment: how to get existing browser?